# Testing a ReactiveVar in Meteor

Tags: testing, meteor

I am trying to test a event in a Template. Within the click event, there is a Reactive Var that gets set.

The test is blocked by the Reactive Var.

Any ideas on how I stub or mock a reactive var in a template? I tried adding it to the template (template.reactiveVar = "whatever"), but no go, as I don't think it's writeable.

The ?? indicate where I am wondering what to put.

it('sets a reactive var when a button is clicked', function(){

```
Template.button.fireEvent('click ', {
    context: { some: 'values'},
    event: {'target': {'text': 'randomText' } },
    templateInstance:new Template('upload', function(e) {
        this.reactiveVar = new ReactiveVar("not clicked)
    })
});

chai.assert.equal(Template.reactiveVar, "clicked")});

// The actual template is below.. 

Template.button.events{(
 'click button': function(evt, template){
   var text = evt.target.text
   template.reactiveVar.set(text)
  }
});
```

The result is...
TypeError: Cannot read property 'set' of undefined

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the event is actually firing and getting through to your event handler before the callback that creates the reactive var has run.

You should create the reactive var when you first create the template independent of your test:

```
Template.button.onCreated(function(){
  this.reactiveVar = new ReactiveVar("not clicked");
});
```